# How to keep minipage close to where it was introduced

Tags: floats, formatting, minipage

I'm writing up a document with a few minipages that keep getting pushed to the end of the document. My minipage is a 4x4 grid of subfigures with a width of `\textwidth` and a height of 16cm. I understand that the reason that the minipage is being put at the bottom of my document is because LaTeX considers it "too tall" and puts it at the next available spot (at the end). However, I don't think that the minipage is too large to fit near its location in my document. Is there a work around to keep the minipage close to where it occurs in the text?

The code I used is attached below:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t][14cm][t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig11.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig12.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig13.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig14.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%  
    \subcaption{Subcaption 1}
\par\vspace{0.125in}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig21.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig22.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig23.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig24.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%  
    \subcaption{Subcaption 2}
\par\vspace{0.125in}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig31.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig32.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig33.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig34.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%  
    \subcaption{Subcaption 3}
\par\vspace{0.125in}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig41.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig42.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig43.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=1.3in]{fig44.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%  
    \subcaption{Subcaption 4}
\par\vspace{0.125in}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{0.125 in}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Figures Float so it's not the minipage that is the problem.

Comment: minipage is positioned with the same logic as a letter, it never moves. Conversely the only function of the `figure` environment is to specify the content can move.